# How to clip a .hdf with shapefile by gdal or other module in Python?

Tags: python, gdal

There is a file (*.hdf, or we can call a raster) and I can open it as array in Python by gdal `ReadAsArray()`. Then, I need to clip it with a shapefile and leave the rest (`B - A ∩ B`). I find everywhere and it may be useful: [clip a raster with shapefile](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clip.html#reading-the-shapefile-and-clipping).

But there are many problems, I just don't know what modules or functions do i need.

Comment: What are the problems you are referring to? What code do you presently have?

Comment: @halfer I just dont know what module or functions do i need